# Mysql regular expression or function for extracting numbers from a specific string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a column that has values of the forms:

```
AB232/10D20
A232/10D20
232/10D20
```

How can I extract the three numbers in mysql? I want to get `232`, `10` and `20` separately and insert them in other columns.

For example, if the the column containing those values is called `original_column`, the query I need is something like this:

```
update mytable
set number_one = something(original_column),
number_two = something2(original_column),
number_three = something3(original_column)
```

Comment: is the string format consistent? or can you have other combinations as well?

Comment: Yes, it's consistent. That's the format I have.

Comment: This is really not going to be easy in MySQL, it's terrible at parsing arbitrary strings. If you have access to *any* scripting language, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Node.js, Java, *anything*, it would be easier than in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query using [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) functions:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET number_one = SUBSTRING(original_column, LOCATE('/', original_column) - 3, 3),
    number_two = SUBSTRING(original_column, LOCATE('/', original_column) + 1, 2),
    number_three = SUBSTRING(original_column, -2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The middle number is easy.  The last number and the first number are pretty easy, if we assume that they are always 3 and 2 characters.

```
update mytable
    set number_one = right(substring_index(original_column, '/', 1), 3),
        number_two = substring_index(original_column, '/', -1) + 0,
        number_three = right(original_column, 2);
```

There are other tricks you can use if the columns are not exactly those lengths.  But in your example, all the values have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

When splitting it using regex, use the group feature. Regex for splitting 3 numbers with non-numeric delimiters (for integers only) would be

([0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9]*)

Use a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) to improve the regex.

Comment: ah, thought for a use case where mysql is accessed from PHP - the scenario wasn't described that exactly, to know HOW the mysql db is used...

Comment: I am directly querying the mysql server.